# Looping thru html files in directory in c using dirent

Tags: c, file, directory-structure

I'm trying to write a program in c that takes in a directory and loops thru the files in the directory. I plan to do some processing on the files and resave them under a new name. I used the dirent struct to get the directory contents, but something goes wrong when I try to get a FILE * out of the dirent.

```
 1 #include <unistd.h>
 2 #include <sys/types.h>
 3 #include <dirent.h>
 4 #include <stdio.h>
 5 #include <string.h>
 6 #include <sys/fcntl.h>
 7 #include <stdlib.h>
 8 #include <sys/stat.h>
 9 #include <errno.h>
 13 char parentName[256];
 14 
 15 void listdir(const char *name, int level)
 16 {
 17     DIR *dir;
 18     struct dirent *entry;
 19 
 20     if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
 21         return;
 22     if (!(entry = readdir(dir))){
 23         closedir(dir);
 24         return;
 25     }
 26 
 27     do {
 28         if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
 29                 printf("Don't give me a directory!!");
 30         }
 31         else{
 32                 FILE *thisFile;
 33                 if(!(thisFile = fopen(entry->d_name, "r"))){
 34                         printf("Error");
 35                 }
 36                 struct stat buf0;
 37                 fstat(fileno(thisFile), &buf0);
 38                 off_t size = buf0.st_size;
 39                 printf("size = %d\n",(int) size);
 40                 printf("Made it here first");
 41                 char *buf1 = (char*) malloc(101);
 42                 printf("Made it here");
 43                 fgets(buf1,100,thisFile);
 55                 printf("%s",buf1);
 56         }
 57     } while ((entry = readdir(dir)));
 58     closedir(dir);
 59 }
 60 
 61 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 62 {
 63         if (argc == 0)  listdir(".", 0);
 64         else listdir((char*)argv[1],0);
 65     return 0;
 66 }
```

The program outputs

size = 12292
Segmentation Fault: 11

And if I delete line 39, it just segfaults. (Also, that size is not close to the size of the file in bytes, chars, or words.) Please help, thank you!

:)

EDIT: included the #includes

Comment: did you try using a debugger?

Comment: please also include the include directives

Comment: I did try using gdb, but I could not get it to tell me what was happening. I'm not very experienced with gdb, trying to get some c cred with this project.

Comment: you could try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`'s, to make sure all debug output is actually printed. (your program works for me)

Answer (score 2):

I see three problems:

1. `argc` is 1 not 0, when you give no arguments. So, change in `main()` to:

   `if (argc == 1)  listdir(".", 0);`
2. When `fopen()` fails, you try to process the file anyway. Either add an `else` or `continue` the loop:

   `if(!(thisFile = fopen(entry->d_name, "r"))){`
       `printf("Error");`
       `continue;`
   `}`
3. You have a memory leak. You allocate `buf1`, but you never `free()` it.

Comment: 1. Good catch, thanks
2. Also a good suggestion, but it never prints "Error" so this was not the source of my problem. 
3. Also a valid point, I left it out because the program never gets there. 

Thanks for your help

Comment: one more: there is a `fopen`, but no `fclose`.